Classification of groups with order 12: Dicyclic Group
I am trying to classify all groups with order 12. Currently I am stuck at the case with $s_2 =3$ and $s_3 = 1$, that is, $G$ has 3 Sylow $2$-subgroups, call them $P$, and one Sylow $3$-subgroup $Q$.
I showed that if $P$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$, it is generated by an element $p \in P$ with order 4 and $Q$ is generated by an element $q \in Q$ with order 3.
Futhermore, I showed that for all $p \in P$ and $q \in Q$ the equality $pqp^{-1} = q^2$ holds.
At last I arrived at the conclusion, that in this case the group has the presentation $$G \cong \langle p,q \,|\, p^4 = 1, q^3 = 1, pqp^{-1} =q^2 \rangle$$ and thus is isomorphic to the dicyclic group of order 12.
But how can I prove that $p$ and $q$ generate such a group, because they only generate their individual Sylow subgroups?

Hint: show that $p^iq^j$ for $0\le i\le 3$ and $0\le j\le 2$ are all distinct. But isn't this a duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=groups+of+order+12

Thanks, I looked through the posts before posting but none of them really seemed to answer this specific aspect of the classification.

Thanks for telling me (I was too lazy to check). Is my hint sufficient to you?

I will try it in about 2-3 hours, then I'll get back to you.
